# Run github action only on last commit

Tags: github, github-actions, gitleaks

So I'm trying to run `gitleaks` through `github-actions` and using in their yaml file.

My goal is to run the gitleaks only on the last commit, means that if someone got *error* because having leaks in the code he need to fix that and just commit again and it will work.

Right now if i run it like it is it look on all the commits history and check that (and it's not good because if i fixed my leaks it should pass)

This is the yaml:

```
name: gitleaks

on: [pull_request]

jobs:
  gitleaks:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: gitleaks-action with defaults
        uses: zricethezav/gitleaks-action@master
      - name: gitleaks-action with config
        uses: zricethezav/gitleaks-action@master
        with:
          config-path: .gitleaks.yml
```

after reading little bit i tried to use:

```
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: '0'
```

but '0' still gives me all the commits history.
tried to change to 1 or 2 and now it passed anyway (also if there is leaks in the code) and i got:

> time="2021-12-21T13:52:58Z" level=info msg="commits scanned: 0"

How could i make it to run only on the last commit?

Answer (score 0):

PierreBis is correct, but that command will bring no results.

You should add -p also in the --log-opts parameter.
The line below should works:

```
gitleaks detect --source . --log-opts "-p -n 1"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use '--log-opts ' gitleaks option to set commit limite ([Gitleaks doc](https://github.com/zricethezav/gitleaks#detect)).

So to get only the last commit, you should use '-n 1' to limit the number of commits at one.

Whole gitleaks commande looks like: `gitleaks detect --source . --log-opts "-n 1"`

Notes: That doesn't limit github Action but gitleaks

Notes2: That will only test diff given by last commit (i.e: result of `git log -p -n 1` command)